# wordpress ACF array custom query AND OR

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Problem: ACF field has array of IDs (stored as strings) not obeying WPQuery (custom query)

Data of post_meta.meta_key = 'EventTopicId'

> a:3:{i:0;s:2:"10";i:1;s:2:"32";i:2;s:2:"30";}

I have several other meta_key fields that, combined, create a filter for WPQuery. (e.g. EventTopicId + CategoryId + ...)

Id's are passed as array. When using 'IN' operator the query returns 0 results.
This is the closest I've found to what I believe I need.
[Array into Comma separated array in PHP.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53480510/array-into-comma-separated-array-in-php)

```
$metaSearchQuery[] =[
   'key'          => 'EventTopicId',
   'value'        => $eventTopicId,
   'compare'      => 'IN'
];
```

The problem is that my MetaQuery is an AND relationship (filter1 + filter2 etc).
The assumption was 'IN' would do the job on ACF field... But if I pass an array of 10
$eventTopicId= ['10']; then zero results returned.

[image]

The above returns 0 results.
EndDates and SessionDetails data are OK for posts I'm testing.
It seems that the correct SQL would be

> ( mt1.meta_key = 'EventTopicId' AND ( mt1.meta_value like '"10"' OR
> mt1.meta_value like '"11"'  ... )

How would one craft a WP search query with multiple meta_keys, some strings, some arrays.

NOTE: I've tried this to cast as string with little results

```
array_walk($eventTopicId, function(&$value, $key) {
   return $value = '"'.$value.'"';
   //return $value = (string) $value;
});
```

UPDATE: This raw SQL works.

[image]

So the question still remains: How can you craft an SQL like this using WPQuery and MetaData.

Answer (score 0):

The result was indeed another nested array using this answer as inspiration:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/104060/using-or-conditions-in-meta-query-for-query-posts-argument

```
'meta_query' =>
        array(
           'relation' => 'AND', // default relation
            array(
                'key' => 'met_key_1',
                'value' => '1128',
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
            ),
            array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'key' => 'meta_key_2',
                    'value' => 'Friday',
                    'compare' => 'LIKE',
                ),
                array(
                    'key' => 'meta_key_2',
                    'value' => 'Saturday',
                    'compare' => 'LIKE',
                ),
            )
        )
```

So the resultant SQL was indeed AND between meta fields and OR within a specific SERIALISED dataset within a single meta field.

I looped over the IDs passed and created an $orSearch list
[image]

[image]